# how to update table with method from C# console app?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have tried to make an update method in C#

I have Database class :

```
        public SqlConnection connection()
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = "DESKTOP-UPVVOJP";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "Lagersystem";
            builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            return new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
        }
```

And Product class :

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int ProductStock { get; set; }
        public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
        public int ProductEmployeeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProductCreatedDate { get; set; }

        // Constructor
        public Product(string productname, int productstock, int productcategoryid, int productemployeeid)
        {
            ProductName = productname;
            ProductStock = productstock;
            ProductCategoryID = productcategoryid;
            ProductEmployeeID = productemployeeid;
            ProductCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

In my program i have the UpdateProduct method :

```
static void UpdateProduct(string updateproductname, int updateproductstock, int updateproductcategoryid, int updateproductemployeeid, string updateproductid)
        {
            Database db = new Database();
            SqlConnection conn = db.connection();
            conn.Open();
            using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE Products (ProductName, ProductStock, ProductCategoryID, ProductEmployeeID)
                SET ProductName = @productname, 
                ProductStock = @productstock, 
                ProductCategoryID = @productcategoryid, 
                ProductEmployeeID = @productemployeeid 
                WHERE ProductID = @productid", conn);
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@productid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = updateproductid;
                command.Parameters.Add("@productname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32).Value = updateproductname;
                command.Parameters.Add("@productstock", SqlDbType.Int).Value = updateproductstock;
                command.Parameters.Add("@productcategoryid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = updateproductcategoryid;
                command.Parameters.Add("@productemployeeid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = updateproductemployeeid;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

that i am calling from my main method :

```
Console.Write("Hvilket produkt ID vil du slette?: ");
                        string updateproductid = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Indtast nyt Produktnavn: ");
                        string updateproductname = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Hvor mange er der på lager?: ");
                        int updateproductstock = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Hvilken kategori ID hører produktet til?: ");
                        int updateproductcategoryid = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Hvilket medarbejder ID har rettet produktet?: ");
                        int updateproductemployeeid = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        try
                        {
                            UpdateProduct(updateproductname, updateproductstock, updateproductcategoryid, updateproductemployeeid, updateproductid);
                            Console.WriteLine("\n" + updateproductname + " Opdateret med success!\n\n");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
```

When i try to run it, i get the an error saying that my SQL query has an Incorrect syntax near '('.
When i debug to check if the parameters are correct, everything seems fine
i get the correct id, and correct value in each parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UPDATE` syntax is incorrect you don't need the column names in () as you would in an INSERT statement:  `Products (ProductName, ProductStock, ProductCategoryID, ProductEmployeeID)`  before the `SET`.

**Generic Sample**:
`UPDATE tableName Set ColumnName = @columnValue, ColumnName2 = @columnValue2 WHERE KeyColumn = @key`.

Reference: [Update Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Kudos on using this syntax: `command.Parameters.Add("@productid", SqlDbType.Int).Value`

Comment: Thank you! this was the solution, and thank you for the kudos, i am just now learning c#. and most of what i know is comming from asking people like you here on stackoverflow!

Comment: Best in your journey on learning C#, databases.  I highly recommend these SQL Server sites for software developers (they offer a lot of free content and videos): http://nettrax.net/links/  (Brent Ozar, Erik Darling, Pinal Dave),  in the past year I have learned so much more about databases from them.